# Is it possible when I click the browser back button go back specific old url?

Tags: javascript

I have a cart page, when I increase a products count, I'm refreshing the page. Therefore when I click the back button, I can't go to where I come to cart. When I come to cart first time, I am saving the referrer url in localstorage. When the user increases the product count and when the page refresh I want to inject my localstorage url to history.

I am adding old url to localstorage  like this:

```
if (window.location.pathname === '/cart' &&  document.referrer.include("/cart")) {
    const refererUrl = document.referrer;
    localStorage.setItem('refererUrl', refererUrl);
}

window.addEventListener('popstate', (event) => {
  if (localStorage.getItem('refererUrl')) {
    const refererUrl = localStorage.getItem('refererUrl');
    window.location.replace(refererUrl);
  }
});
```

Comment: *"I have a cart page, when i increase a products count refreshing page."* - I don't understand what you mean here. Care to explain? Users can also navigate to that URL by directly using the browser history. So in general you should fix whatever you have on that page or solve it server-side instead of influencing the user's browsing experience.

Comment: Well basically history manipulation is a big no go, a wonder it havent been disabled already.. IF YOU MUST, (please don't) you can (ab-)use the page hash for this.
But as @PeterKrebs mentioned, go serverside, use ajax or something for a smooth update. and if you use ajax, no history will be written, thus the user keeps his normal history. And btw: you're using localStorage for the url's but you save the count of the articles in the url? Why not save the Articles in the localStorage instead??

Comment: @PeterKrebs sorry for my bad english,  We can increase the count of products added to the cart. But every time we increase it, the page is refreshed and added to this history. For this reason, when you want to go back, it still stay on the card page.

Comment: That looks like an XY problem. Because you implemented the cart so weirdly you are now trying to fix its symptoms. Consider creating an API you can call via AJAX and don't transfer the user's cart information via URL.

Comment: @Dxg125 we will change it to ajax but i am searching short term solution. I don't understan your last question. I am saving to localstorage where come from to  cart.

Comment: @AlperUluses I'm talkin about the fact that you're saving the pages / history, but why not save the cart data into localStorage instead of the History (thus you wouldn't need to reload)? isn't saving the history absolutely useless, if you can save the current cart data into the localStorage instead?